Issue with Cyrillic Anchors Not Scrolling to Headers in MKDocs Material
Problem Description
I’m using Obsidian and have set up a vault where my notes reference each other using specific headers. When I try to follow a link (using anchors) to a header on another page, the link takes me to the correct page, but it doesn’t scroll to or highlight the specific header that the anchor is supposed to lead to.
Is there a way to make Obsidian automatically scroll to the correct header when following these anchor links?
Environment

Python 3.12.3 (Ubuntu 24.04)
MKDocs 1.6.0
MKDocs Material 9.5.31

Config
theme:
  name: material
  features:
    - navigation.instant
    - navigation.tabs
plugins:
  - search
markdown_extensions:
  - toc:
      permalink: "#"

Extract of notes
One file
...
- [Reference](access_inheritance.md#наследование-доступов-в-дереве-отделов) of something...

Another file
...

## Наследование доступов в дереве отделов
Some context...

The possible root cause

The href attribute in the reference HTML's pointing to ... The id attribute in the source HTML is set as: ... The href link seems to include a slugified version of the heading, but the id in the source HTML doesn't match it directly. In English all is matched.

I’ve tried changing the language of the header, and while this temporarily fixed the issue, it isn’t a viable solution for me as I need to use Cyrillic.
If anyone has encountered this issue before and found a solution, I’d appreciate any insights you can share. If this turns out to be a bug, I’ll make sure to report it in the appropriate place.

Don't ask a question in your title, summarize your problem. And remember: you don't want "yes"/"no" answers, you want help solving a problem. So don't ask yes/no questions, talk about the problem you're having instead =)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thx) fixed it

If you look at the generated HTML, what does it actually contain? E.g. what HTML does mkdocs generate for that reference link, and what HTML does it generate for that heading? Because my immediate thought is that your reference link points to an .md file, but there are no markdown files after converting your content to static pages. That should probably be a relative page URL, not a file URL.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
The href attribute in the reference HTML's pointing to <a href="http://localhost:8000/multiserver/staff_app/access_inheritance/#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2">...</a>
The id attribute in the source HTML is set as: <h2 id="_3">...</h2>
The href link seems to include a slugified version of the heading, but the id in the source HTML doesn't match it directly. But in English all is matched.

Looks like the root cause...

Remember: don't tell "me", put that information in your post. It's part of the problem description. This is information relevant to the problem that you found by debugging (you should have of course checked this before posting, but any relevant information that you dig up after posting still needs to go in your post, so that people who never saw your post before get the complete picture)

Add this to mkdocs.yml
markdown_extensions:
  - toc:
      slugify: !!python/object/apply:pymdownx.slugs.slugify
        kwds:
          case: lower

it works for me
docs
